# C++ Bluetooth WSAGetLastError 10108

Tags: c++, sockets, bluetooth

I have a problem with my bluetooth socket code. I am getting `WSAgetErrorCode 10108` and I think it is because I can't find my bluetooth device, or because my device is not supported on Windows 7. I don't understand how to get my dongle (`König CSBLUEKEY100`) to work properly.

```
#define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS

#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "irprops.lib")

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
#include <ws2bth.h>
#include <BluetoothAPIs.h>
#include <bthdef.h>


#define SCK_VERSION2 0x0202
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define MAX_NAME 248
typedef ULONGLONG BT_ADDR;


using namespace std;


int main()
{

WSADATA wsadata_bt;
WSAQUERYSET sokBT;
WSAQUERYSET *hittadeBTresultat;
WORD wsadata_version;
DWORD bufferLangdBT;
DWORD namnrymd;
HANDLE hittaBT;
BYTE bufferBT[4096];
BT_ADDR adressBT;
LPTSTR BT;


int wsa_ansluten; 
int bt_ansluten;
int enheter_hittade;


//Deklarera värden för wsa och aktivera wsa och BT
wsadata_version = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
wsa_ansluten = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsadata_bt); 
memset(&sokBT, 0, sizeof(WSAQUERYSET));
bt_ansluten = WSALookupServiceBegin(&sokBT, LUP_CONTAINERS, &hittaBT);
memset(bufferBT, 0, sizeof(bufferBT));
bufferLangdBT = sizeof(bufferBT);
hittadeBTresultat = (WSAQUERYSET*) &bufferBT;


//Skapa BT-värden
sokBT.dwSize = sizeof(WSAQUERYSET);
sokBT.dwNameSpace = NS_BTH;
sokBT.lpBlob = NULL;

if (wsa_ansluten != 0)
{
    printf("\tERROR: Kunde inte initialisera winsock.dll\n"); 
    printf("\tFelkod: %id", WSAGetLastError());
    WSACleanup();
    system("Pause");
    return 0;
    }
  else
  {
    printf("Initialiserar Winsock...\t\tOK!\n");
  }

 if (bt_ansluten != 0)
 {
    printf("\tERROR: Kunde inte initialisera bluetooth.dll\n");
    printf("\tFelkod: %id", WSAGetLastError());
    WSACleanup();
    system("Pause");
    return 0;
 }
 else
 {
    printf("Initialiserar Bluetooth...\t\tOK!\n");
    system("cls");
 }

//Sök efter bluetoothenheter

while (wsa_ansluten && bt_ansluten == 0)
{
        enheter_hittade = WSALookupServiceNext(hittaBT, LUP_RETURN_NAME |  LUP_CONTAINERS | LUP_RETURN_ADDR |
    LUP_FLUSHCACHE | LUP_RETURN_TYPE | LUP_RETURN_BLOB | LUP_RES_SERVICE, &bufferLangdBT, hittadeBTresultat);
    if (enheter_hittade == 0)
    {
        adressBT = ((SOCKADDR_BTH *)hittadeBTresultat->lpcsaBuffer->RemoteAddr.lpSockaddr)->btAddr;
        BT = hittadeBTresultat->lpszServiceInstanceName;
        namnrymd = hittadeBTresultat->dwNameSpace;
        wprintf(L"\tENHET\tNAP ADRESS\tSAP ADRESS\tNAMNRYMD\n");
        wprintf(L"\t%s\t0X%04X\t\t0X%08X\t0X%0X\n", BT, GET_NAP(adressBT), GET_SAP(adressBT), namnrymd);
    }


}



WSACleanup();
system("PAUSE");
return 0;
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the you have Microsoft Bluetooth Enumerator installed (On Drivers control panel applet).
2. Try to add LUP_RETURN_ADDR with LUP_CONTAINERS (LUP_CONTAINERS | LUP_RETURN_ADDR).